# Visualize all short paths in graph using R

Tags: r, igraph

The first simple data

```
m <- read.table(row.names = 1, header = TRUE, text = 
                  "  A   B   C   D   E   F
                A 0   1   1   1   1   5
                B 1   0   1   1e2 1e2 1
                C 1   1   0   1   1   1
                D 1   1e2 1   0   1e2 1
                E 1   1e2 1   1e2 0   1
                F 5   1   1   1   1   0")
m <- as.matrix(m)
```

Using igraph library

```
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE)
sp <- shortest.paths(ig, algorithm = "dijkstra")
plot(ig)

spaths <- lapply(V(ig),
                 function(v){
                     all_shortest_paths(ig, v,
                                        weight = 1 / E(ig)$weight
                     )
                 }
           )
```

Now let's check paths to all vertices spaths$C$res or spaths$B$res... How can I display only one shortest path from one point to another on the graph? 1.For example From C to A as red line 2.and the longest way from C to A as blue line

Comment: "longest way from C to A as blue line" - Do you want the longest _simple_ path from C to A? Since your graph has cycles, unless you restrict to simple paths, there are arbitrarily long paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you want the longest *simple* path from C to A.  Since your graph has cycles, there are paths of arbitrarily large lengths if you revisit nodes. Let me first answer the question, but there is a caveat at the end.

You can get all simple paths from C to A using `all_simple_paths`. From those, it is easy to select one of the shortest paths and one of the longest paths. Then just color them.

```
Simple = all_simple_paths(ig, "C", "A")
SP = which.min(sapply(Simple, length))
LP = which.max(sapply(Simple, length))

EL1 = rep(Simple[[LP]], each=2)[-1]
EL1 = EL1[-length(EL1)]
EL2 = rep(Simple[[SP]], each=2)[-1]
EL2 = EL2[-length(EL2)]

ECol = rep("gray", ecount(ig))
ECol[get.edge.ids(ig, EL1)] = "blue"
ECol[get.edge.ids(ig, EL2)] = "red"

plot(ig, edge.color=ECol)
```

[image: Longest and Shortest paths colored]

But be warned! If your graph is big and well connected, there may be *many* paths between two nodes. `all_simple_paths` may take a long time to run and produce a very large result.